# Children of z-index: 'auto' vs z-index: 0, and what is "stacking context" in CSS?

Tags: html, css, z-index

Previously, I believed that a child element could not be z-indexed over an element that is a sibling of its parent element that has a higher z-index than its parent. For example, divs A and B are siblings. `Div A` has a z-index of 10, and `div B` has a z-index of 5. `Div B` has a child element: `Div C`, with a z-index of 9999. From my understanding, `div C` will *not* be positioned above `div A`, because `div C`'s parent (`div B`) has a lower z-index than `div A`. This holds true, unless `div B` has a z-index of 'auto'. When `div B` has a z-index of 'auto', which would be '0', as it is inheriting from body, `div C` positions over `div A`, even though div B's z-index is actually **LOWER** than it was when it wasn't working.

From the CSS2 spec, z-index 'auto' is defined as

*The stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context is 0. The box does not establish a new stacking context unless it is the root element.*

I'm having trouble understanding "*stacking context.*" It seems to be the only difference between a defined z-index of 0, and a default of 'auto' which is 0 but also has no stacking context. More specifically:

**Why are children of elements with no stacking content z-indexed differently than those within a stacking context?**

Here is a fiddle that shows the difference between z-index of 0, and a z-index of auto. The green div is a child of the blue div, and the red div is a sibling of the blue div.

http://jsfiddle.net/c7Tvt/

Comment: A shorter answer might be: you need a default stacking order to deal with any non-positioned element on the page that do not have an explicitly set z-index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you have two scenarios, call them Blue and Blue-2.

In Blue, you have two stacking contexts, the first contains `#blue` and the second contains `#red` and `#green`.  `#blue` is in its own stacking context because `z-index: auto`, and this context is simply part of the default stack.

In Blue-2, you have defined `z-index: 0` for `#blue`, so it is part of the same stacking context as `#red`.  In Blue-2, `#blue` is painted first because it has the lowest z-index, 0.  However, `#green` is a child of `#blue` and gets painted over `#blue`, the parent and child form a new stacking context (a sub-stacking context if you wish).
Finally, `#red` is painted over the blue-green stack because the red z-index is 2, which is greater than the blue z-index of 0.  In this case, the z-index of green affects its stacking level with respect to blue and any other child elements in `#blue`.  In Blue-2, there are three stacking contexts, the default (#1), the one for red and blue (#2), and the other that is blue and green (#3).

**Key Point**
`z-index: auto` does not start add a positioned element to a new stacking context whereas `z-index: 0` does.  Remember, there is at least one stacking context, the default one that is defined for the elements by virtue of their natural HTML/DOM order on the page.

**Note:** I took the liberty of describing the staking position as if you had two web pages, one with `#red`, `#blue`, `#green` and the second with `#red2`, `#blue2`, `#green2`.  In reality, since all the div's are on the same page, all the stacking levels contain all the elements.  When there are two red div's in the same stack, `#red2` would be painted over `#red` since elements further down the DOM tree are painted over earlier elements.

**Reference**
I found the following quite useful to read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context_example_2

If you want even more detail, try looking at:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html

Comment: Thanks. I now understand why things work the way that they do in example #2. I pretty much understand example #1, except for one part. I understand that `#blue` is part of the default SC, and that `#red` has created its own SC. But, it would seem that #green has created a new SC, and its parents are in the default SC. How are #green and #red in the same SC? I can observe that this is true, but I don't understand why.

Edit: Are #green and #red in the same SC because both of their parent's are in the same SC (both parent's are in the default SC)?

Comment: I just reread the following http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers and I think that you are right, in example #1, #green does define a new stacking content (SC), which becomes more apparent if you position something in it, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/c7Tvt/1/ in this case, the yellow child div with text follows the green div.

Comment: #green and #red are descendents of the root element's stacking order and are painted in the order given by their z-index value.  The easiest way to understand how this works is to think in terms of the painting order as descried in the w3 doc, Appendix E.  The concept of stacking context is not as easy to explain as the open/close curly brackets in programming languages such as C or JavaScript that define the scope of a programming block.

Comment: I think the key to it is that while defining a z-index creates a new SC for all the child elements of the z-indexed div, the z-indexed div itself will always be in the SC of the parent element.